# How to get the names of all the files in a folder and display them in an HTML document using JS?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Say there are several files in a folder. I want to display the names of all these documents in a list in an HTML page. How to realize it using JS?

Comment: Only if you want to use **ActiveXObject** (IE only)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using JavaScript or any client-side browser-sandboxed code, as web pages do not have direct filesystem access, and therefore cannot get directory listings.

Comment: unless its node.js ;)

Comment: @andymccullough You could definitely use Node.js to do the directory listing and serve it to the browser, but then there wouldn't be any HTML file (it would be dynamically generated)